# Excel 2007 IF AND function calculation not copying across

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm using an IF AND function, which is:

```
=IF(F3<$F$60,F3*$C$55,IF(AND($F$60<F3,F3<$E$60),($F$60*$C$55)+((F3-$F$60)*$C$56),IF(AND(F3>$E$60),($F$60*$C$55)+(($E$60-$F$60)*$C$56)+((F3-$E$60)*$C$57))))
```

Which works correctly in the original input cell.

But when I copy that across to the adjacent cells (assessing the data series F3, G3, H3, I3 and J3), the formula works fine for the latter 3 cells, but the cell immediately next to the input cell (the one working off G3) just states 'FALSE'.

I've looked at the cell formatting of G3 and its precedent cells and they are all the same as the formatting of the formatting of F3, H3, I3 and J3.

Comment: Do all the cells being referenced have values? And are the types correct? I mean, are you comparing a number to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're missing your final false.  I've laid it out differently so you can see:

```
=IF(
    G3<$F$60
    ,G3*$C$55
    ,IF     (
        AND  ($F$60<G3,G3<$E$60)
        ,   ($F$60*$C$55)+ ((G3-$F$60)*$C$56)
        ,   IF   (
            AND(G3>$E$60)
            ,  ($F$60*$C$55)+(($E$60-$F$60)*$C$56)+((G3-$E$60)*$C$57)
            MISSING--->",  ?????"
                  )
             )
    )
```

Also, did you intend `AND(G3>$E$60)`?  As a single condition it doesn't need `AND`.

Comment: Many thanks Dave and Madball. I am only looking for a numerical answer to my calculation, not a "statement". I wanted to copy the spreadsheet to this but don't think I can? The strange thing is that the formula works fine when calculating from F3, H3, I3 and J3 inputs (when copied across), but for some reason the G3 calculation doesn't work. Which suggests to me the formula isn't the problem? As per the Qu - - I've looked at the cell formatting of G3 and its precedent cells and they are all the same as the formatting of the formatting of F3, H3, I3 and J3. V grateful for your insight. Alex

Comment: What we are saying is that the input of G3 may not meet any of the conditions listed, and thus when you do not provide fallback value/calculation, Excel automatically returns False.  What are the values of G3, E60, & F60?

Comment: G3=110.9, E60=111, F60=55.... Aha! You have prompted the solution: E60 is rounded up and was actually exactly the same number as G3, which must have been causing the formula to say 'FALSE'. I've changed the input number to G3 by just 0.01% (which keeps the calculation essentially the same) and that has allowed the formula to work. So am v pleased to have a fully working formula now, v many thanks Madball

Comment: Great.  I would suggest still entering a final condition, even if it's "I'm broken" :)  Please accept either answer.

Comment: yes it does show instead of false if I insert it. I guess the problem is that the IF formula i was using was directing the calculation if the input cell was greater than or less than the assessment cell, but the problem I had was that for one area of the G3 formulation the input cell was exactly the same as one of the measurement cells (110.9) and as I hadn't included in the formula what to do for equals, it just said "FALSE"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the final false statement (see the end of the statement)

```
=IF(F3<$F$60,F3*$C$55,IF(AND($F$60<F3,F3<$E$60),($F$60*$C$55)+((F3-$F$60)*$C$56),IF(AND(F3>$E$60),($F$60*$C$55)+(($E$60-$F$60)*$C$56)+((F3-$E$60)*$C$57),"I am an empty false condition, alone and unloved")))
```

If you use this, you'll *probably* see that your formula doesn't do what you are hoping when you adjust the cells and you're not capturing a condition... Because you didn't state the last 'false' condition it was just displaying false, which was probably confusing!